# Linking problems with AppKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I've created a class using XCode3.2.1 and I want to make it inherit from NSViewController (or any other AppKit entity) .

```
#import < Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface myCustomView : NSViewController {}

@end
```

I've linked in the Cocoa libraries, but I get the error that it can't find the class header file

```
Undefined symbols: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSViewController", referenced from:
    _OBJC_CLASS_$_myCustomView in myCustomView.o
```

I have other classes in my project that are inherit Cocoa classes without a problem.   I don't have any errors if I make it inherit from classes that are part of Framework or CoreData (eg NSObject, NSArray, NSEntityDescription).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work. I built a new project and created a class exactly like you have it, can't duplicate your error. Check your project settings, something is fishy.

Comment: To extend JakeVA's point. this should work.  I had a similar problem the other day.  I created a new project and everything worked out fine.  I would create a simple new project if i were you and see if you could extend NSViewController. If so, just spend the extra time and work your project into it.

Comment: I made a new project as well and everything works fine.  I have the Cocoa framework added to the original project, I have another class in the same project inheriting from NSWindowController that doesn't complain.  I'd obviously prefer not to recreate the project class-by-class if it's just some XCode issue that I've screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your subclassed `NSViewController` implementation file is in the "Compile sources" build phase of your active target.

Comment: It's there under compile sources.

Comment: Is that space after '<' charater in import statment a typo or actual code?

Comment: No, sorry, it was a formatting mistake.  Additionally, if I make the class inherit from NSObject, I can add a class variable of type NSViewController without a compiling error.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the some of the Frameworks become disconnected in XCode.
Under if you control-click Frameworks and select GetInfo, it the
box had a dash through it (meaning it was partially selected).
Clicking it again activated it for all classes.